# How can i create a pop up list of values in oracle apex that validates logged in user?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to show the employee name/id of only the logged in user so that he can put his own id/name in the insert sale record. is that possible and if so how will i be able to do it in that specific field in the form. in my example i want only zhr123 to appear in the pop up list of values. [Please refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQtCS.png)

Comment: Why would you show a Popup LOV for this? If the only value the user can select is his/her own name, then it seems like you could just do this for them. Is there a need for null? Or do you intend to do this by setting the item's Read Only attribute to Always?

Answer (score 1):

Once you're logged in, `:APP_USER` contains your username.

Therefore, if it has to be a select list item (though, I don't know why as there won't be anything to choose among), include such a condition into its `where` clause:

```
select name
from your_table
where name = :APP_USER         --> this
```

Perhaps you'd just rather use it (i.e. the `:APP_USER`) as item's default value.